# Nodeenv throws no python virtualenv is available

Tags: python, django, virtualenv, django-compressor

I have python virtualenv and trying to install nodeenv it throws

`"no python virtualenv is available"`

inside my activated python virtual env with  `. bin/activate`

I run the following commands

`pip install nodeenv`

```
nodeenv -p
```

And it throws the error... I'm currently trying to install less with django-compressor

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This also happened to me, it's because nodeenv is not installed in your virtual environment. The following solved it for me:

```
sudo pip uninstall nodeenv
# Source your virtual environment.
source /path/to/virtualenv
pip install nodeenv
nodeenv -p
```

Comment: Weirdly, I had to reactivate the venv before nodeenv --version showed the version I'd just installed

Answer (score 1):

This happened to me on Mac OSX Yosemite.

I had installed nodeenv as a user.  The solution was to install it as root:

```
pip uninstall nodeenv
sudo pip install nodeenv
# Source the virtual environment or use workon for virtualenvwrapper
workon <virtualenv name>
nodeenv -p
```